# Python CSV: nested double quotes

Tags: python, csv

I have a `test.csv` file as follows:

```
"N";"INFO"
"1";"<a href="www.google.it">www.google.it</a>"
```

I use the following program to print out the contents of the CSV file

```
import csv
with open('test.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader=csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
    for p in reader:
        print("%s %s" % (p['N'], p['INFO']))
```

The output is

```
1 <a href=www.google.it">www.google.it</a>"
```

The reason lies probably in the fact that the csv file has some "nested" double quotes. However, the separating character is ";", and so I would like the library to simply remove the double quote " at the beginning and at the end of the field INFO, keeping  the rest of the string intact.

In other words, I would like the output of the program to be

```
1 <a href="www.google.it">www.google.it</a>
```

How can  I fix that, without modifying the `test.csv` file?

Comment: Hmm, possibly you could fiddle with the various CSV dialect settings, but most likely you'll need to do at least some of the handling yourself, eg. disabling the quotechar in the CSV reader and removing the quotes yourself...

Comment: One important question - does the INFO field ever contain a semicolon?

Comment: @JiříBaum No, the INFO does never contains a semicolon.

Comment: Can you use `split(';')` instead of the `csv` module to parse the data? Then just remove the double quotes with `strip('"')` manually?

Comment: Yeah, using `split(';')` is one option; another would be to use `csv` module with `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE` or similar, then stripping the quotes off the individual fields

Comment: @David I suppose this could be possible, but I would rather prefer to use the CSV library.The reason is, unlike the minimal example above, the CSV is more complex and has more fields.

Comment: A third option would be to use regular expressions

Comment: @JiříBaum Using ```quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE``` and ```quotechar=''``` has the somewhat annoying consequence that ```DictReader``` does include ```"``` in the field names.

Comment: Yeah... have to fiddle with it to make it work; I think I've got an answer for you, though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to use the `csv` module with `csv.QUOTE_NONE`, then handle the removal of the quotes (on both the fieldnames and the values) manually:

```
import csv

def strip_outer_quotes(s):
    """ Strip an outer pair of quotes (only) from a string. If not quoted,
    string is returned unchanged. """
    if s[0] == s[-1] == '"':
        return s[1:-1]
    else:
        return s

def my_csv_reader(fh):
    """ Thin wrapper around csv.DictReader to handle fields which are
    quoted but contain unquoted " characters. """
    reader = csv.DictReader(fh, delimiter=';', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    reader.fieldnames = [strip_outer_quotes(fn) for fn in reader.fieldnames]
    for row in reader:
        yield {k: strip_outer_quotes(v) for k, v in row.items()}

with open('test.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = my_csv_reader(csvfile)
    for p in reader:
        print("%s %s" % (p['N'], p['INFO']))
```

Note: instead of `my_csv_reader`, probably name the function after the source of this particular variant of CSV; `acme_csv_reader` or similar